# How to display Username on successive pages of login without PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, url

I want to display username on Homepage and so on like "Hi," extracting from URL.

```
<div id="login">
    <form method="post" action="">
        <h2>Login</h2>
        <p>
            <label for="username">Username: </label>
            <input type="text" name="username" /> </p>
        <p>
            <label for="pwd">Password: </label>
            <input type="password" name="pwd" /> </p>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Login" name="submit" /> </p>
    </form>
```

Comment: please explain your problem give some code

Comment: What you have tried so far ?

Comment: I am using post method in the form so it will have username and password. But I am unable to display using $_session ['username'].

Comment: can you put the form code

Comment: please display related full code in question only..

Comment: <div id="login">
 <form method="post" action="">
     <h2>Login</h2>
        <p>
         <label for="username">Username: </label>
            <input type="text" name="username" />
        </p>
        
        <p>
         <label for="pwd">Password: </label>
            <input type="password" name="pwd" />
        </p>
        
        <p>
         <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Login" name="submit" />
        </p>
    </form>

Comment: @Akshaya.L.Bhat never puth the code like this in comments. edit your question instead. Back to your quest... you want to post this form and then put the username in session?

Answer (score 0):

This following javascript code will allow you to get a search variable from the url i.e.

```
www.example.com?query=search
```

will provide you with an object

```
{query: search}
```

---

```
//Code to get search string from urlParams
var match,
    pl     = /\+/g,  // Regex for replacing addition symbol with a space
    search = /([^&=]+)=?([^&]*)/g,
    decode = function (s) { return decodeURIComponent(s.replace(pl, " ")); },
    query  = window.location.search.substring(1);

var urlParams = {};
while (match = search.exec(query)){
    urlParams[decode(match[1])] = decode(match[2]);
}
```

I can't take credit for this code, it's from another stackoverflow question, I just can't find it right now

Answer (score 0):

Just answering your question... you can do that like this:

Create other page to "receive the POST" from login, for example:

**login_user.php**

```
<?php
session_start();

$username = null;
$password = null;

$homepage = 'http://www.your-website-url-here.com';

if ($_SERVER['RQEUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
  if (!empty($_POST['username'])) {
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    // check in database if this user and password matchs

    // put the username in session
    $_SESSION['msg'] = "Welcome $username";
    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;

    // then redirec to home
    header("Location:$homepage");
  } else {
    // some validatoin message to user
    $_SESSION['msg'] = "Validate the e-mail and password";

    // then redirect back
    header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
  }
} else {
  // is not a post request
  $_SESSION['msg'] = "You can't access this page";

  // put the username in session
  header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
}
exit;
```

Then, edit your login form and put this new `login_user.php` in the `action` attribute:

```
<form method="post" action="login_user.php">
```

After that you can capture the username using `$_SESSION` array.

*Remember to put `session_start();` in your homepage file (first line)*

---

### Note

The title of your question is: **without php**, but you said in comments **I try to get with `$_SESSION` but I can't**.

So... is with or without php? My solution is in php only.

---

### Observation / Attetion

This is not the best and security way to do that.

I only answer the question based on what do you need and not what the best way to do that.

I say that because: You must ensure that your login information actually came from the requested page also validates the data to not allow sql injection or any other type of attack in your server files and/or in  database. So think of it first before continuing your work.

---

Hope this helps you.

*Sorry for my english*